# Определить какое кол-во людей было в январе и в какой день

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, обработка-данных

Есть CSV файл с данными даты в форматe год-месяц-день (1 столбец) и второй столбец это кол-во человек.

Как определить какое кол-во людей было в январе и в какой день?

```
Date       Per
2014-01-01   0
2014-01-02   3
2014-01-03   5
2014-01-10   10
```

Попытка решения:

```
ss = pd.read_csv('out.csv')
ss['Date'].value_counts()
```

Comment: с чем именно у вас возникли трудности: с чтением CSV? с выбором данных за январь? с подсчетом строк за каждый день? Уточните вопрос и приведите в вопросе вашу попытку решения

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @MaxU выбор данных за январь, и подсчетом

Comment: @MaxU ss = pd.read_csv('out.csv')
              ss['Date'].value_counts(). Я понимаю как это работает, но как сделать подсчет именно за определенный месяц?

Comment: можете привести в вопросе (воспользуйтесь кнопкой "править" под вопросом) первые 3-5 строк из CSV файла?

Comment: @MaxU готово)))

Comment: @MaxU а как мне получить день с наибольшим значением людей?

Comment: здесь принято задавать отдельные вопросы. Если у вас возник новый вопрос - откройте новый SO вопрос и не забудьте привести в нем пример данных и результат который вы хотите получить;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv("out.csv", parse_dates=["Date"])
d = df.loc[df["Date"].dt.month == 1].groupby(df["Date"].dt.day).sum()
```